# Usar atributo html como variável javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP que utiliza de uma extensão para formulários dinâmicos, onde eu posso clicar em um botão para adicionar campos (EX: Um pedido pode ter vários itens, onde os itens são os campos adicionados dinamicamente).

A extensão que utilizo (não creio que seja necessário mencionar, visto que o problema não é com ela) possui em sua configuração um parâmetro onde eu posso especificar o limite de campos que se pode adicionar dinamicamente, podendo ser infinito ou não.

Quando a extensão é renderizada, ela gera um trecho de código em javascript, onde neste trecho, se encontra uma variável que contém um JSON com os parâmetros estabelecidos anteriormente, dentre eles o parâmetro "limit", que é o parâmetro que eu desejo alterar em tempo de execução.

Até aí tudo bem... O problema é que a tal variável que contém o JSON, possui um sufixo aleatório no nome, como por exemplo **dynamicform_5ed2807a** ou **dynamicform_7fg2802c**.

O nome dessa variável eu consigo descobrir, pois existe uma div com a classe fixa *dynamicform-wrapper* que contém o atributo *data-dynamicform*, sendo que o valor desse atributo é exatamente o nome da variável.

Diante disso, tentei fazer da seguinte forma, sem sucesso:

```js
var x = $(this).attr('data-dynamicform');
console.log(x.limit); // Note que limit é o nome da 'key' que eu quero pegar o valor
```

No exemplo acima, ele retorna **undefined**, sendo que deveria retornar um número inteiro, que é o limite de campos.

**EDIT**
Segue link do JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wuoo6Lpm/

Como posso fazer para resolver esse problema?
Muito obrigado!

Comment: podes mostrar como está o HTML desse elemento com o `data-dynamicform`? Se isso fôr um JSON precisas de fazer `var x = JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-dynamicform'));`

Comment: Olá. Na verdade o atributo html está assim: ``data-dynamicform="dynamicform_5ed2807a"``.
O JSON é a variável que quero acessar, que tem o mesmo nome do atributo.

Comment: Então o que esperas que retorne com `x.limit`?

Comment: Espero retornar o valor de limit, que está na variável javascript de mesmo nome. Veja:     ``var dynamicform_5ed2807a = {"widgetContainer":"dynamicform_wrapper","widgetBody":".container-encaminhamentos","widgetItem":".item-encaminhamento","limit":4}``

Comment: Ah, estou a ver. E essa variável é criada como? via PHP? podes mudar a maneira como é criada?

Comment: Ela é criada com nome aleatório, por isso preciso acessá-la pelo atributo data-dynamicform, pois o valor dele é o mesmo nome da variável.

Comment: Mas podes controlar esse JavaScript no PHP? podes mudar para ser por exemplo `dynamicforms.dynamicform_5ed2807a = {"widgetCont... `? Sem `var`, mas adicionando uma nova propriedade a um objeto.

Comment: Não, pois em caso de atualização da extensão em PHP, perco todas as alterações que fiz. E ela é atualizada via gerenciador de dependêncais.

Comment: ok... e essa `var` está no escopo global pelo menos?

Comment: Sim. Está parecido com isso: https://jsfiddle.net/wuoo6Lpm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se essa variável que é gerada pelo PHP está no escopo global podes aceder via objeto `window` com colchetes (parentesis retos).

Podes então aceder assim:

```
var chave = $(this).attr('data-dynamicform');
var x = window[chave];
console.log(x.limit);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzmoh983/

Comment: Funcionou!
Muito obrigado Sergio!!

Comment: @jflizandro ótimo! Fiz muitas perguntas para perceber melhor o problema :)